# Creating Custom Text Edit Control

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I am trying to create a custom textbox for a windows universal platform app, one that isn't derived from the TextBox class. The reason that I don't want to derive it from TextBox (or RichEditBox for that matter) is that it has its limitations.

I have found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/custom-text-input?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#working-with-text) on MSDN which gives an overview of the Custom Text Input APIs for UWP, but it doesn't explain a lot on how to even get started.

I would really appreciate it if you could provide me with some information that better explains how to create a custom text editing control, or if you could provide me with a sample that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official document: [Custom text input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/custom-text-input) has been updated and in [**Related articles**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/custom-text-input#related-articles) you can find a new sample: [**Custom Edit Control sample**](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=831024).

This sample is newly added in official [Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). You can get start by referring to this sample and the official document. For more information about this sample, please see its [**README**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomEditControl#custom-edit-control-sample).

Besides, there are also another sample: [UI.Text.Core-Sample](https://github.com/teatime77/UI.Text.Core-Sample) and article written in Japanese that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really nice that they updated the samples master for the anniversary update. I also checked out the second (japanese) sample, and in my opinion it is a little bit better than the first one, as it is more complete, such a shame I don't speak Japanese.